# Create a new object with property-value pairs from an other object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
const ingredients = {
  fruit: 'orange', liquid: 'water', vegetable: 'tomato', spices: 'curry'
};
```

I want to pick some of the properties from `ingredients` and add them to a new object - `shoppingList`.

Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
const shoppingList = {};
shoppingList.fruit = ingredients[fruit];
shoppingList.spices = ingredients[spices];
```

Is there any more convenient way of doing the above? I'm envisioning a function of some sort to which I can give `ingredients`, `fruit` and `spices` and it will return a new object with those properties and values.

Comment: Not sure how this could possibly work.... `const object.property` is not a valid js statement. `const name = value`  should be the only thing which works.

Comment: @JaSuperior i think it's a typo

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to generate a new object based on keys that you pass to a function.

Small running example:

```js
const ingredients = {
  fruit: 'orange',
  liquid: 'water',
  vegetable: 'tomato',
  spices: 'curry'
};

function pick(keys, obj) {
  const newObj = keys.reduce((result, currentKey) => {
    result[currentKey] = obj[currentKey];
    return result;
  }, {});
  return newObj;
}


const myKeys = ['fruit', 'spices'];
const customObj = pick(myKeys, ingredients);
console.log(customObj);
```

If you want to go really crazy you can add it to the `Object.prototype` and invoke it directly on objects.
Note that this will add the `pick` method to all objects, so maybe consider adding it just to some of your objects:

```js
const ingredients = {
  fruit: 'orange',
  liquid: 'water',
  vegetable: 'tomato',
  spices: 'curry'
};


Object.prototype.pick = function(keys){
  const newObj = keys.reduce((result, currentKey) => {
    result[currentKey] = this[currentKey];
    return result;
  }, {});
  return newObj;
}

const myKeys = ['fruit', 'spices'];
const customObj = ingredients.pick(myKeys);
console.log(customObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function which destructures it the way you like.

```
function  applySpicesandFruit ({ fruit,  spices}) { 
    this.fruit = fruit; 
    this.spices = spices 
    return this;
}
applySpicesandFruit.call(shoppinglist, ingredients);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to provide you a function, I just believe this way goes more clean

```js
const ingredients = {
  fruit: 'orange',
  liquid: 'water',
  vegetable: 'tomato',
  spices: 'curry'
}

//ingredients, fruit and spices

const {
  fruit,
  spices
} = ingredients

const newObj = {
  fruit,
  spices
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(newObj))
```